# Rank of a block-matrix which implies a zero block

Tags: linear-algebra

Why if I have a matrix like this one:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
 I_k & 0 \\ 
 B & C
\end{array} \right),
$$
which have rank k I can automatically say that $C=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Because the span of the first $k$ rows (row rank = column rank, remember?) lies entirely in the span of $e_1, \ldots, e_k$ (where these are standard unit ROW vectors). If there were a nonzero entry in $C$, then the row containing that nonzero entry, say $v$, could not be written as a linear combination of the first $k$ rows, hence $\{e_1, \ldots, e_k, v \}$ would be linearly independent, and the rank would be at least $k+1$, hence not $k$.

Comment: Because row rank  = column rank. Alternatively, suppose that the *column* vector containing the nonzero entry in $C$ is $w$. Then because the rank of $M$ is $k$, and the first $k$ columns $u_1, \dots, u_k$ are independent (I leave it to you to show this), the vector $w \ne 0$ can be written as a *nonzero* linear combination $w = a_1 u_1 + \ldots + a_k u_k$. But the first $k$ entries of this linear combination are (by direct computation) exactly $a_1, \ldots, a_k$, and those must be the first $k$ entries of $w$, which are all zeroes, hence the linear combination is zero -- a contradiction.

Comment: All clear, thank you so much.